# Сравнение элементов объекта и выдача результатов на основе сравнений

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

стоит задача получить массивы из объектов.
Имеется 3 массива из объектов с содержимым бд. Объекты Driver, Cars, Driver_Cars. Соответственно имеются 3 класса с такими же названиями. С геттерами и сеттерами для свойств классов. Поэтому выводить отдельно эти таблицы я могу. Но мне нужно вывести Имя, Фамилия и авто этого владельца. Поэтому используется таблица Driver_Cars. На каждого владельца несколько авто. Чтобы вывести это написал метод для поиска соответствий между этими таблицами, состоял он из более чем из 10 foreach и условий. Типо такого:

```
public function($a, $b, $c){
foreach($a as $class=>$object){
  foreach($object as $key=>value){
    foreach($b as $class1=>$object1){
      foreach($object1 as $key1=>value1){
        if($value==$value1 && $key==$key1){
          return....
....
....
}}}}}
}
```

Он в принципе работает, но это просто ужас. Потому что это только для соответствий a и b
Про итераторы читал, попробовал реализовать, но вышло плохо.
Прошу помочь в реализации решения.
Фото класса(остальные реализованы так же)
Фото таблиц
И фото отладки. Так же есть класс для работы с бд но он только обрабатывает запросы и формирует объекты в массив.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите один простой SQL-запрос да выполните, ну зачем на PHP этот ужас-то городить? Два тривиальнейших JOIN, ну, может, ещё ORDER BY - и всё.

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем вам здесь вообще объекты, если в итоге нужно получить массив. Если уж нужны объекты - в любом случае сначала выполняйте один запрос к бд и формируйте массив нужной структуры (или коллекцию объектов нужной структуры)